# error lvalue required as a left operand of assignment

Tags: bit-manipulation, lvalue

```
fprintf(obFile,"\t%s\t%s\n",intToBase32((unsigned int)address),intToBase32((unsigned int)(atoi(infoArray[i].operand2)<<=2)));

fprintf(obFile,"\t%s\t%s\n",intToBase32((unsigned int)address),intToBase32((unsigned int)(getRegister(infoArray[i].operand2)<<=2)));

fprintf(obFile,"\t%s\t%s\n",intToBase32((unsigned int)address),intToBase32((unsigned int)(atoi(infoArray[i].operand1)<<=2)));
```

i get the error: lvalue required as a left operand of assigment

on these and more like this lines in c, cannot understand what is the problem.

needed information:
FILE *obfile;

int address;

infoArray is a array of structs. infoArray[i].operand1 and infoArray[i].operand2 are strings of numbers. example : "5", "-10".

/*Gets unsigned int and returns base 32 string by dividing for groups of 5 bits */
char * intToBase32(unsigned int num)

finally i need to get a line wtih address in base 32 and a number in base 32, while the number should be shifted 2 bits left before converting to base 32.

Comment: What's the `=` part of  `<<=2` meant to do?

Comment: Shift left for(=) 2 bits

Comment: get rid of the `=`. Just do `<<`.  You can't assign to the result of a function call.